# Compare columns of two CSV files and delete differences

Tags: python, linux, bash, csv, compare

I would like to compare two huge CSV files with different amount of enties. Just one column contains the same values like they are also exisitng in the other file in the same column, which is much bigger.

So I want to keep the lines in one of the files where a line with the same value in the second file also exists.

Example:

```
File a
value1,value2,value3,...
value4,value5,value6,...
value7,value8,value9,...

File b:
value10,value2,value11,...
value12,value13,value14,...
```

In the end file b (or a complete new file) should look like this:

```
value10,value2,value11,...
```

I don't believe it's that hard, but at the moment I have no idea how to achieve this. How could I get there with linux tools or a bash/python script?

Thanks for any hint!

Comment: Basically You want to achieve B.Columns-A.Colums ?

Comment: What is "huge" and how big is the difference in file size (and number of rows)?

Comment: @ChetanKulkarni correct, want to get rid of differences related to one column.

Comment: @hop around 166000 (76MB) lines compared to around 56000 (18MB) lines

Comment: @Kay: that's called small

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In awk:

```
$ awk -F, '
NR==FNR {               # hash elements in the first file to a
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
        a[$i]
    next
}
{                       # second file
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)  # go thru all elements
        if($i in a) {   # if match
            print       # output
            next        # and skip to next record
        }
    }
' file1 file2
value10,value2,value11
```

This one hashes the first file in the memory. If by *huge* you mean more-than-your-memory-can-handle, this might not be the solution for you.

Comment: Well, "huge" might not be the correct term. It can be handled by the memory. I think that helps. Thanks!